# Drop rows by string in column value

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have dataframe with 2 columns and a few thousands of rows. What I need now is drop out, delete, rows which contains 'css', 'jpg', 'png', 'favicon', etc. in column values. 
It looks like this:

```
Referer      Count

favicon.ico   24
ponto.css     21
mobil/net     16
private/net   14
ort.jpg       11
```

The desired output is this:

```
   Referer      Count

    mobil/net     16
    private/net   14
```

I've tried with this:

```
df[df['Referer'].str.contains('css', 'jpg', 'png', 'favicon.ico')]
```

But this is what I got:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need `|` what is `or` in regex and then invert boolean mask by `~`.

So need `css` or `jpg` ...

```
df = df[~df['Referer'].str.contains('css|jpg|png|favicon.ico')]
print (df)
       Referer  Count
2    mobil/net     16
3  private/net     14
```

If values are in list, is possible use `join` with `|` - output is same.

```
L = ['css','jpg','png','favicon.ico']

df = df[~df['Referer'].str.contains('|'.join(L))]
print (df)
       Referer  Count
2    mobil/net     16
3  private/net     14
```

Comment: Glad can help you! Nice day!

Comment: @jezrael, you are really fast :-)

Comment: @Praveen - Sometimes yes, sometimes not. But I think your solution is same, so the best is delete it. Thanks

Comment: @jezrael i guess, bracket notation is better than dot notation.

Comment: Yes, obviously yes. There is also problem with columns like `sum`, `mean` if use dot notation.